# Route not found but why it happend

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in D:\Server\htdocs\new_try\routes\web.php:14 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Server\htdocs\new_try\routes\web.php on line 14
```

`Route` is not found, but I don't know why?

Comment: Do you think you have stated enough information? welcome to stack overflow , please read [mcve], add code trials if any, add enough information what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us more details, procedure you followed to install Laravel, pieces of code, etc. I'll still try to help you:

Verify that in your `config/app.php`, in the `aliases` array, you have this line:

```php
'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
```

also, please make sure you have a `vendor` folder in the root of your project (in this case: `D:\Server\htdocs\new_try`). If you don't have one, you didn't install correctly Laravel. You have to do `composer install` in order to fetch all the required dependencies.